# How to extract the first column in grep command and pass to next command in linux cmd?

Tags: linux, windows, cmd, cmder

I using [cmder](https://cmder.net/) in windows - kind a bash with command prompt.

In this cmder I run a command:

```
kubectl get pod
```

and I get those results:

```
NAME                                READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
alpine-d4c458d59-4xxxxsb            1/1     Running     0          31d
cron-my-ecr-1618xxxx-hdcjq          1/1     Running     0          16h
cron-ecr-renew-1618xxxx800-zdxps    1/1     Running     0          10h
```

I want to run another command base on the result:

```
kubectl logs cron-my-ecr-1618xxxx-hdcjq
```

My question is how I run one command instead of two and avoid copy-paste?

What I was able to do is run by grep:

```
kubectl get pod | grep cron-my-ecr
```

Which give me the one row of result:

```
cron-my-ecr-1618xxxx-hdcjq          1/1     Running     0          16h
```

But how I extract the first column and pass it to the next command?

Comment: You can do it with cut, awk, or sed. Possibly others but those are the first ones that come to mind.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
kubectl get pod | grep cron-my-ecr | awk '{print $1}';kubectl describe po $(!!)
```